# Input views aren't filling the correct inputs, or responding to the initial action

Tags: bixby

I have two actions with required inputs:

- **TwoInputs** collects String, Integer1
- **ThreeInputs** collects the same as **TwoInputs** plus Integer2.

I also have an input-view for each of the inputs.

If I request **ThreeInputs** with no inputs using…

```
intent {
  goal: ThreeInputs
}
```

*It correctly* requests each input, one at a time: String, Integer1, Integer2.

*It incorrectly* then returns a result for **TwoInputs** with String and Integer2 as the value for Integer1.

How can I get the input-views to return the ThreeInputs result?

Comment: What is the concept of Integer1 and Integer2, same or different?

Comment: String:book_name, Integer:chapter_number, Integer:verse_number

Comment: So, when I trigger a Verse action, then respond to "Book?" > "James", "Chapter?" > "2", "Verse?" > "3" I end up with a "James 3" Chapter response. ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add prompt training for input.

John 3 verse -> 16

what happened is that utterance "16" is treated as a new utterance and pickup missing chapter "John" as previous input. It would be much more clear if you add **feature { transient }** to all 3 concepts.